# Analysis Services in Visual Studio gives error "Invalid token 'Text' at root level of document."

Tags: azure-analysis-services

For a few years I'm using Visual Studio to build an analysis services cube. So I have a solution with a Model.bim file in it. This used to work fine (though it could be slow).

Now it gives the error messages
"Invalid token 'Text' at root level of document." and "XML document must contain a root level element." I'm  still able to deploy the model, but when I want to switch to Designer mode, it refuses because it thinks the syntax is not right.

Updating Visual Studio did not help. Maybe I have to change something in the properties or configuration.

Does somebody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Fixing this was impossible. I made a new solution and copy-pasted my script into it and now it works again.